# How to fill the area below a curve in a chart with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, fill

I would like to divide the graph into 3 zones and fill each one with a color and put the names of the areas. Look at the code (commented part) that I tried to do it for the first zone, but it did not work. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % utf8 Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
}



\begin{document}

% Definição do Estilo e dos Eixos   
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest,xmin=0,xmax=8500,ymin=2}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xlabel=Tempo(s), ylabel=Tensão (V),,grid=major,ytick distance=0.5]

\addlegendentry{Curva de Descarga}

% Plotagem dos Pontos para plotagem do gráfico

\addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {    

    (  0.00,   4.20309810)
    ( 10.00,   4.15772650)
    ( 20.00,   4.15530300)
    ( 30.00,   4.15246890)
    ( 40.00,   4.14982030)
    ( 50.00,   4.14731730)
    ( 60.00,   4.14493360)
    ( 70.00,   4.14261600)
    ( 80.00,   4.14041760)
    ( 90.00,   4.13827220)
    (100.00,   4.13617980)
    (110.00,   4.13410060)
    (120.00,   4.13208760)
    (130.00,   4.13008790)
    (140.00,   4.12812790)
    (150.00,   4.12616790)
    (160.00,   4.12422120)
    (170.00,   4.12230090)
    (180.00,   4.12039390)
    (190.00,   4.11852660)
    (200.00,   4.11664610)
    (210.00,   4.11479200)
    (220.00,   4.11295120)
    (230.00,   4.11109720)
    (240.00,   4.10926960)
    (250.00,   4.10742880)
    (260.00,   4.10564090)
    (270.00,   4.10385310)
    (280.00,   4.10203880)
    (290.00,   4.10025100)
    (300.00,   4.09847640)
    (310.00,   4.09670180)
    (320.00,   4.09491390)
    (330.00,   4.09316580)
    (340.00,   4.09144420)
    (350.00,   4.08969610)
    (360.00,   4.08796120)
    (370.00,   4.08623950)
    (380.00,   4.08447820)
    (390.00,   4.08276980)
    (400.00,   4.08106140)
    (410.00,   4.07932660)
    (420.00,   4.07759170)
    (430.00,   4.07590980)
    (440.00,   4.07421470)
    (450.00,   4.07253280)
    (460.00,   4.07081120)
    (470.00,   4.06912930)
    (480.00,   4.06746070)
    (490.00,   4.06577880)
    (500.00,   4.06409690)
    (510.00,   4.06244150)
    (520.00,   4.06073310)
    (530.00,   4.05907770)
    (540.00,   4.05743560)
    (550.00,   4.05576690)
    (560.00,   4.05409830)
    (570.00,   4.05244290)
    (580.00,   4.05077420)
    (590.00,   4.04913210)
    (600.00,   4.04748990)
    (610.00,   4.04583450)
    (620.00,   4.04421880)
    (630.00,   4.04256340)
    (640.00,   4.04094780)
    (650.00,   4.03929240)
    (660.00,   4.03766340)
    (670.00,   4.03602130)
    (680.00,   4.03441890)
    (690.00,   4.03278990)
    (700.00,   4.03114780)
    (710.00,   4.02951890)
    (720.00,   4.02791640)
    (730.00,   4.02628750)
    (740.00,   4.02468510)
    (750.00,   4.02306940)
    (760.00,   4.02145380)
    (770.00,   4.01985130)
    (780.00,   4.01823570)
    (790.00,   4.01662000)
    (800.00,   4.01500430)
    (810.00,   4.01341510)
    (820.00,   4.01181270)
    (830.00,   4.01021030)
    (840.00,   4.00860780)
    (850.00,   4.00704510)
    (860.00,   4.00544270)
    (870.00,   4.00382700)
    (880.00,   4.00225110)
    (890.00,   4.00067520)
    (900.00,   3.99908600)
    (910.00,   3.99747030)
    (920.00,   3.99588110)
    (930.00,   3.99427870)
    (940.00,   3.99268950)
    (950.00,   3.99108710)
    (960.00,   3.98951110)
    (970.00,   3.98790870)
    (980.00,   3.98631950)
    (990.00,   3.98471710)
    (1000.00,   3.98315420)
    (1010.00,   3.98153850)
    (1020.00,   3.97994930)
    (1030.00,   3.97837340)
    (1040.00,   3.97679740)
    (1050.00,   3.97523470)
    (1060.00,   3.97206960)
    (1070.00,   3.97049370)
    (1080.00,   3.96894420)
    (1090.00,   3.96735500)
    (1100.00,   3.96581880)
    (1110.00,   3.96428260)
    (1120.00,   3.96271990)
    (1130.00,   3.96118370)
    (1140.00,   3.95962100)
    (1150.00,   3.95808480)
    (1160.00,   3.95653530)
    (1170.00,   3.95498590)
    (1180.00,   3.95343640)
    (1190.00,   3.95191340)
    (1200.00,   3.95039050)
    (1210.00,   3.94884100)
    (1220.00,   3.94730480)
    (1230.00,   3.94578180)
    (1240.00,   3.94425890)
    (1250.00,   3.94269620)
    (1260.00,   3.94122620)
    (1270.00,   3.93967670)
    (1280.00,   3.93818020)
    (1290.00,   3.93665730)
    (1300.00,   3.93514750)
    (1310.00,   3.93365110)
    (1320.00,   3.93212810)
    (1330.00,   3.93790210)
    (1340.00,   3.93643210)
    (1350.00,   3.93493570)
    (1360.00,   3.93338620)
    (1370.00,   3.93190300)
    (1380.00,   3.93039320)
    (1390.00,   3.92888350)
    (1400.00,   3.92737380)
    (1410.00,   3.92586410)
    (1420.00,   3.92436760)
    (1430.00,   3.92284460)
    (1440.00,   3.92136140)
    (1450.00,   3.91987810)
    (1460.00,   3.91836840)
    (1470.00,   3.91688520)
    (1480.00,   3.91537540)
    (1490.00,   3.91389220)
    (1500.00,   3.91240890)
    (1510.00,   3.91095220)
    (1520.00,   3.90944250)
    (1530.00,   3.90795920)
    (1540.00,   3.90648920)
    (1550.00,   3.90503250)
    (1560.00,   3.90356250)
    (1570.00,   3.90209250)
    (1580.00,   3.90064900)
    (1590.00,   3.89919220)
    (1600.00,   3.89777520)
    (1610.00,   3.89633170)
    (1620.00,   3.89488820)
    (1630.00,   3.89343140)
    (1640.00,   3.89200120)
    (1650.00,   3.89055760)
    (1660.00,   3.88912740)
    (1670.00,   3.88772360)
    (1680.00,   3.88630660)
    (1690.00,   3.88487630)
    (1700.00,   3.88344600)
    (1710.00,   3.88204230)
    (1720.00,   3.88061200)
    (1730.00,   3.87924750)
    (1740.00,   3.87780400)
    (1750.00,   3.87644000)
    (1760.00,   3.87500970)
    (1770.00,   3.87361920)
    (1780.00,   3.87221540)
    (1790.00,   3.87081160)
    (1800.00,   3.86942110)
    (1810.00,   3.86801730)
    (1820.00,   3.86664000)
    (1830.00,   3.86524950)
    (1840.00,   3.86385890)
    (1850.00,   3.86249490)
    (1860.00,   3.86109110)
    (1870.00,   3.85971380)
    (1880.00,   3.85834980)
    (1890.00,   3.85697250)
    (1900.00,   3.85560840)
    (1910.00,   3.85424440)
    (1920.00,   3.85289360)
    (1930.00,   3.85155600)
    (1940.00,   3.85019190)
    (1950.00,   3.84884110)
    (1960.00,   3.84750360)
    (1970.00,   3.84615280)
    (1980.00,   3.84480200)
    (1990.00,   3.84346440)
    (2000.00,   3.84212680)
    (2010.00,   3.84078930)
    (2020.00,   3.83946490)
    (2030.00,   3.83816710)
    (2040.00,   3.83684280)
    (2050.00,   3.83553170)
    (2060.00,   3.83420740)
    (2070.00,   3.83290950)
    (2080.00,   3.83158520)
    (2090.00,   3.83027420)
    (2100.00,   3.82896310)
    (2110.00,   3.82766520)
    (2120.00,   3.82636740)
    (2130.00,   3.82508280)
    (2140.00,   3.82375850)
    (2150.00,   3.82247390)
    (2160.00,   3.82118930)
    (2170.00,   3.81991800)
    (2180.00,   3.81865990)
    (2190.00,   3.81737530)
    (2200.00,   3.81607740)
    (2210.00,   3.81484580)
    (2220.00,   3.81358770)
    (2230.00,   3.81230310)
    (2240.00,   3.81105830)
    (2250.00,   3.80978690)
    (2260.00,   3.80854200)
    (2270.00,   3.80729720)
    (2280.00,   3.80607880)
    (2290.00,   3.80479420)
    (2300.00,   3.80356260)
    (2310.00,   3.80233100)
    (2320.00,   3.80108610)
    (2330.00,   3.79984130)
    (2340.00,   3.79860960)
    (2350.00,   3.79736480)
    (2360.00,   3.79615960)
    (2370.00,   3.79494130)
    (2380.00,   3.79372290)
    (2390.00,   3.79251780)
    (2400.00,   3.79131260)
    (2410.00,   3.79010750)
    (2420.00,   3.78891560)
    (2430.00,   3.78769720)
    (2440.00,   3.78651860)
    (2450.00,   3.78531340)
    (2460.00,   3.78413480)
    (2470.00,   3.78295620)
    (2480.00,   3.78177750)
    (2490.00,   3.78059890)
    (2500.00,   3.77942020)
    (2510.00,   3.77824160)
    (2520.00,   3.77706290)
    (2530.00,   3.77593730)
    (2540.00,   3.77475850)
    (2550.00,   3.77359310)
    (2560.00,   3.77240120)
    (2570.00,   3.77124910)
    (2580.00,   3.77011010)
    (2590.00,   3.76897120)
    (2600.00,   3.76780580)
    (2610.00,   3.76668010)
    (2620.00,   3.76554120)
    (2630.00,   3.76440230)
    (2640.00,   3.76327660)
    (2650.00,   3.76216420)
    (2660.00,   3.76101210)
    (2670.00,   3.75988640)
    (2680.00,   3.75878720)
    (2690.00,   3.75766150)
    (2700.00,   3.75654910)
    (2710.00,   3.75543670)
    (2720.00,   3.75436400)
    (2730.00,   3.75325150)
    (2740.00,   3.75217880)
    (2750.00,   3.75107960)
    (2760.00,   3.74999370)
    (2770.00,   3.74890780)
    (2780.00,   3.74786150)
    (2790.00,   3.74677560)
    (2800.00,   3.74567640)
    (2810.00,   3.74461700)
    (2820.00,   3.74350450)
    (2830.00,   3.74245830)
    (2840.00,   3.74141210)
    (2850.00,   3.74035260)
    (2860.00,   3.73927990)
    (2870.00,   3.73822050)
    (2880.00,   3.73718750)
    (2890.00,   3.73611480)
    (2900.00,   3.73509510)
    (2910.00,   3.73404890)
    (2920.00,   3.73301590)
    (2930.00,   3.73199620)
    (2940.00,   3.73096320)
    (2950.00,   3.72995670)
    (2960.00,   3.72895020)
    (2970.00,   3.72791730)
    (2980.00,   3.72695050)
    (2990.00,   3.72591750)
    (3000.00,   3.72493750)
    (3010.00,   3.72393110)
    (3020.00,   3.72295110)
    (3030.00,   3.72195780)
    (3040.00,   3.72095130)
    (3050.00,   3.71999780)
    (3060.00,   3.71903110)
    (3070.00,   3.71802460)
    (3080.00,   3.71704460)
    (3090.00,   3.71606460)
    (3100.00,   3.71509780)
    (3110.00,   3.71410460)
    (3120.00,   3.71315110)
    (3130.00,   3.71219760)
    (3140.00,   3.71127060)
    (3150.00,   3.71027730)
    (3160.00,   3.70935030)
    (3170.00,   3.70841000)
    (3180.00,   3.70748300)
    (3190.00,   3.70654270)
    (3200.00,   3.70560250)
    (3210.00,   3.70468870)
    (3220.00,   3.70376170)
    (3230.00,   3.70284790)
    (3240.00,   3.70196060)
    (3250.00,   3.70103350)
    (3260.00,   3.70010650)
    (3270.00,   3.69920600)
    (3280.00,   3.69833190)
    (3290.00,   3.69745790)
    (3300.00,   3.69654410)
    (3310.00,   3.69564360)
    (3320.00,   3.69475630)
    (3330.00,   3.69388220)
    (3340.00,   3.69300820)
    (3350.00,   3.69209440)
    (3360.00,   3.69123360)
    (3370.00,   3.69034630)
    (3380.00,   3.68947220)
    (3390.00,   3.68862470)
    (3400.00,   3.68775060)
    (3410.00,   3.68688980)
    (3420.00,   3.68604220)
    (3430.00,   3.68518140)
    (3440.00,   3.68433390)
    (3450.00,   3.68348630)
    (3460.00,   3.68265200)
    (3470.00,   3.68180440)
    (3480.00,   3.68098330)
    (3490.00,   3.68016220)
    (3500.00,   3.67934120)
    (3510.00,   3.67852010)
    (3520.00,   3.67769900)
    (3530.00,   3.67690440)
    (3540.00,   3.67609660)
    (3550.00,   3.67527550)
    (3560.00,   3.67446770)
    (3570.00,   3.67369960)
    (3580.00,   3.67287850)
    (3590.00,   3.67208390)
    (3600.00,   3.67128930)
    (3610.00,   3.67049470)
    (3620.00,   3.66969990)
    (3630.00,   3.66891860)
    (3640.00,   3.66813720)
    (3650.00,   3.66732940)
    (3660.00,   3.66657450)
    (3670.00,   3.66579320)
    (3680.00,   3.66503830)
    (3690.00,   3.66427020)
    (3700.00,   3.66352860)
    (3710.00,   3.66276050)
    (3720.00,   3.66199240)
    (3730.00,   3.66126400)
    (3740.00,   3.66048260)
    (3750.00,   3.65976750)
    (3760.00,   3.65901260)
    (3770.00,   3.65829750)
    (3780.00,   3.65752940)
    (3790.00,   3.65681430)
    (3800.00,   3.65611240)
    (3810.00,   3.65535750)
    (3820.00,   3.65464240)
    (3830.00,   3.65394050)
    (3840.00,   3.65323860)
    (3850.00,   3.65251020)
    (3860.00,   3.65178180)
    (3870.00,   3.65106670)
    (3880.00,   3.65035160)
    (3890.00,   3.64963640)
    (3900.00,   3.64894780)
    (3910.00,   3.64824590)
    (3920.00,   3.64753080)
    (3930.00,   3.64682890)
    (3940.00,   3.64614020)
    (3950.00,   3.64545160)
    (3960.00,   3.64476290)
    (3970.00,   3.64408750)
    (3980.00,   3.64341210)
    (3990.00,   3.64273670)
    (4000.00,   3.64203480)
    (4010.00,   3.64137270)
    (4020.00,   3.64071050)
    (4030.00,   3.64003510)
    (4040.00,   3.63935970)
    (4050.00,   3.63871080)
    (4060.00,   3.63804860)
    (4070.00,   3.63738650)
    (4080.00,   3.63672430)
    (4090.00,   3.63606220)
    (4100.00,   3.63541320)
    (4110.00,   3.63476430)
    (4120.00,   3.63411540)
    (4130.00,   3.63346650)
    (4140.00,   3.63283080)
    (4150.00,   3.63218190)
    (4160.00,   3.63153300)
    (4170.00,   3.63089730)
    (4180.00,   3.63024840)
    (4190.00,   3.62961270)
    (4200.00,   3.62896380)
    (4210.00,   3.62830160)
    (4220.00,   3.62770570)
    (4230.00,   3.62708330)
    (4240.00,   3.62644760)
    (4250.00,   3.62582520)
    (4260.00,   3.62520270)
    (4270.00,   3.62458030)
    (4280.00,   3.62395790)
    (4290.00,   3.62336190)
    (4300.00,   3.62275270)
    (4310.00,   3.62211710)
    (4320.00,   3.62153440)
    (4330.00,   3.62092520)
    (4340.00,   3.62032920)
    (4350.00,   3.61972000)
    (4360.00,   3.61911080)
    (4370.00,   3.61850170)
    (4380.00,   3.61791900)
    (4390.00,   3.61730980)
    (4400.00,   3.61671380)
    (4410.00,   3.61611790)
    (4420.00,   3.61552190)
    (4430.00,   3.61491270)
    (4440.00,   3.61431680)
    (4450.00,   3.61372090)
    (4460.00,   3.61313820)
    (4470.00,   3.61254220)
    (4480.00,   3.61194630)
    (4490.00,   3.61135030)
    (4500.00,   3.61078090)
    (4510.00,   3.61019820)
    (4520.00,   3.60957570)
    (4530.00,   3.60900630)
    (4540.00,   3.60845010)
    (4550.00,   3.60786740)
    (4560.00,   3.60728470)
    (4570.00,   3.60671520)
    (4580.00,   3.60615900)
    (4590.00,   3.60558950)
    (4600.00,   3.60500680)
    (4610.00,   3.60445060)
    (4620.00,   3.60389440)
    (4630.00,   3.60333820)
    (4640.00,   3.60272900)
    (4650.00,   3.60217280)
    (4660.00,   3.60162980)
    (4670.00,   3.60106030)
    (4680.00,   3.60046440)
    (4690.00,   3.59992140)
    (4700.00,   3.59935200)
    (4710.00,   3.59879580)
    (4720.00,   3.59822630)
    (4730.00,   3.59765680)
    (4740.00,   3.59710060)
    (4750.00,   3.59654440)
    (4760.00,   3.59598820)
    (4770.00,   3.59541870)
    (4780.00,   3.59484930)
    (4790.00,   3.59431960)
    (4800.00,   3.59376330)
    (4810.00,   3.59320710)
    (4820.00,   3.59263770)
    (4830.00,   3.59209470)
    (4840.00,   3.59153850)
    (4850.00,   3.59100870)
    (4860.00,   3.59043930)
    (4870.00,   3.58988310)
    (4880.00,   3.58934010)
    (4890.00,   3.58879710)
    (4900.00,   3.58824090)
    (4910.00,   3.58769790)
    (4920.00,   3.58712850)
    (4930.00,   3.58658550)
    (4940.00,   3.58604250)
    (4950.00,   3.58548630)
    (4960.00,   3.58493010)
    (4970.00,   3.58436070)
    (4980.00,   3.58381770)
    (4990.00,   3.58327470)
    (5000.00,   3.58273170)
    (5010.00,   3.58217550)
    (5020.00,   3.58163260)
    (5030.00,   3.58108960)
    (5040.00,   3.58054660)
    (5050.00,   3.57999040)
    (5060.00,   3.57944740)
    (5070.00,   3.57944740)
    (5080.00,   3.57944740)
    (5090.00,   3.57944740)
    (5100.00,   3.57944740)
    (5110.00,   3.57944740)
    (5120.00,   3.57944740)
    (5130.00,   3.57944740)
    (5140.00,   3.57944740)
    (5150.00,   3.57944740)
    (5160.00,   3.57944740)
    (5170.00,   3.57944740)
    (5180.00,   3.57944740)
    (5190.00,   3.57944740)
    (5200.00,   3.57944740)
    (5210.00,   3.57188560)
    (5220.00,   3.57138230)
    (5230.00,   3.57079960)
    (5240.00,   3.57024340)
    (5250.00,   3.56970040)
    (5260.00,   3.56914420)
    (5270.00,   3.56860120)
    (5280.00,   3.56807150)
    (5290.00,   3.56750200)
    (5300.00,   3.56698560)
    (5310.00,   3.56640290)
    (5320.00,   3.56585990)
    (5330.00,   3.56531690)
    (5340.00,   3.56474710)
    (5350.00,   3.56419080)
    (5360.00,   3.56366110)
    (5370.00,   3.56310490)
    (5380.00,   3.56253540)
    (5390.00,   3.56197920)
    (5400.00,   3.56146270)
    (5410.00,   3.56089330)
    (5420.00,   3.56035030)
    (5430.00,   3.55979410)
    (5440.00,   3.55921140)
    (5450.00,   3.55865520)
    (5460.00,   3.55808570)
    (5470.00,   3.55754280)
    (5480.00,   3.55698650)
    (5490.00,   3.55639060)
    (5500.00,   3.55583440)
    (5510.00,   3.55527820)
    (5520.00,   3.55470870)
    (5530.00,   3.55411280)
    (5540.00,   3.55354330)
    (5550.00,   3.55297380)
    (5560.00,   3.55240440)
    (5570.00,   3.55182170)
    (5580.00,   3.55125220)
    (5590.00,   3.55068280)
    (5600.00,   3.55010010)
    (5610.00,   3.54951740)
    (5620.00,   3.54892140)
    (5630.00,   3.54837840)
    (5640.00,   3.54775600)
    (5650.00,   3.54719980)
    (5660.00,   3.54659060)
    (5670.00,   3.54599470)
    (5680.00,   3.54539870)
    (5690.00,   3.54482930)
    (5700.00,   3.54422010)
    (5710.00,   3.54363740)
    (5720.00,   3.54304140)
    (5730.00,   3.54244550)
    (5740.00,   3.54180980)
    (5750.00,   3.54121390)
    (5760.00,   3.54060470)
    (5770.00,   3.53998230)
    (5780.00,   3.53937310)
    (5790.00,   3.53876390)
    (5800.00,   3.53814140)
    (5810.00,   3.53751900)
    (5820.00,   3.53688330)
    (5830.00,   3.53624770)
    (5840.00,   3.53565170)
    (5850.00,   3.53498960)
    (5860.00,   3.53438040)
    (5870.00,   3.53374470)
    (5880.00,   3.53312230)
    (5890.00,   3.53248660)
    (5900.00,   3.53183770)
    (5910.00,   3.53118880)
    (5920.00,   3.53056630)
    (5930.00,   3.52990420)
    (5940.00,   3.52928170)
    (5950.00,   3.52861960)
    (5960.00,   3.52798390)
    (5970.00,   3.52732170)
    (5980.00,   3.52667280)
    (5990.00,   3.52602390)
    (6000.00,   3.52537500)
    (6010.00,   3.52469960)
    (6020.00,   3.52402420)
    (6030.00,   3.52337530)
    (6040.00,   3.52268660)
    (6050.00,   3.52199800)
    (6060.00,   3.52130930)
    (6070.00,   3.52063390)
    (6080.00,   3.51997180)
    (6090.00,   3.51929640)
    (6100.00,   3.51858120)
    (6110.00,   3.51791910)
    (6120.00,   3.51723040)
    (6130.00,   3.51652850)
    (6140.00,   3.51585310)
    (6150.00,   3.51515120)
    (6160.00,   3.51446260)
    (6170.00,   3.51377390)
    (6180.00,   3.51311180)
    (6190.00,   3.51237020)
    (6200.00,   3.51168150)
    (6210.00,   3.51099290)
    (6220.00,   3.51027770)
    (6230.00,   3.50956260)
    (6240.00,   3.50888720)
    (6250.00,   3.50814560)
    (6260.00,   3.50745690)
    (6270.00,   3.50672850)
    (6280.00,   3.50601340)
    (6290.00,   3.50525860)
    (6300.00,   3.50454340)
    (6310.00,   3.50381500)
    (6320.00,   3.50308670)
    (6330.00,   3.50234500)
    (6340.00,   3.50160340)
    (6350.00,   3.50082210)
    (6360.00,   3.50008050)
    (6370.00,   3.49932560)
    (6380.00,   3.49854420)
    (6390.00,   3.49781590)
    (6400.00,   3.49703450)
    (6410.00,   3.49626640)
    (6420.00,   3.49548510)
    (6430.00,   3.49470370)
    (6440.00,   3.49392240)
    (6450.00,   3.49314100)
    (6460.00,   3.49234640)
    (6470.00,   3.49155180)
    (6480.00,   3.49077050)
    (6490.00,   3.48996260)
    (6500.00,   3.48914160)
    (6510.00,   3.48832050)
    (6520.00,   3.48751260)
    (6530.00,   3.48669160)
    (6540.00,   3.48583080)
    (6550.00,   3.48502290)
    (6560.00,   3.48414890)
    (6570.00,   3.48330130)
    (6580.00,   3.48244050)
    (6590.00,   3.48157970)
    (6600.00,   3.48070560)
    (6610.00,   3.47983160)
    (6620.00,   3.47894430)
    (6630.00,   3.47807020)
    (6640.00,   3.47716970)
    (6650.00,   3.47628240)
    (6660.00,   3.47540840)
    (6670.00,   3.47452110)
    (6680.00,   3.47363380)
    (6690.00,   3.47273320)
    (6700.00,   3.47183270)
    (6710.00,   3.47094540)
    (6720.00,   3.47007130)
    (6730.00,   3.46918400)
    (6740.00,   3.46827030)
    (6750.00,   3.46742270)
    (6760.00,   3.46652220)
    (6770.00,   3.46562160)
    (6780.00,   3.46476080)
    (6790.00,   3.46390000)
    (6800.00,   3.46299950)
    (6810.00,   3.46215190)
    (6820.00,   3.46126460)
    (6830.00,   3.46039060)
    (6840.00,   3.45948990)
    (6850.00,   3.45862910)
    (6860.00,   3.45775510)
    (6870.00,   3.45688100)
    (6880.00,   3.45598050)
    (6890.00,   3.45511970)
    (6900.00,   3.45424560)
    (6910.00,   3.45333180)
    (6920.00,   3.45245780)
    (6930.00,   3.45155720)
    (6940.00,   3.45065670)
    (6950.00,   3.44976940)
    (6960.00,   3.44885560)
    (6970.00,   3.44794180)
    (6980.00,   3.44702810)
    (6990.00,   3.44610100)
    (7000.00,   3.44516080)
    (7010.00,   3.44423370)
    (7020.00,   3.44325370)
    (7030.00,   3.44234000)
    (7040.00,   3.44134670)
    (7050.00,   3.44035350)
    (7060.00,   3.43940000)
    (7070.00,   3.43836700)
    (7080.00,   3.43733400)
    (7090.00,   3.43630110)
    (7100.00,   3.43525480)
    (7110.00,   3.43416890)
    (7120.00,   3.43306970)
    (7130.00,   3.43197050)
    (7140.00,   3.43087130)
    (7150.00,   3.42969270)
    (7160.00,   3.42851400)
    (7170.00,   3.42733540)
    (7180.00,   3.42611700)
    (7190.00,   3.42487220)
    (7200.00,   3.42361410)
    (7210.00,   3.42232950)
    (7220.00,   3.42099190)
    (7230.00,   3.41962780)
    (7240.00,   3.41823730)
    (7250.00,   3.41679380)
    (7260.00,   3.41531060)
    (7270.00,   3.41380080)
    (7280.00,   3.41223810)
    (7290.00,   3.41062250)
    (7300.00,   3.40898030)
    (7310.00,   3.40725870)
    (7320.00,   3.40549730)
    (7330.00,   3.40365650)
    (7340.00,   3.40172300)
    (7350.00,   3.39974980)
    (7360.00,   3.39771030)
    (7370.00,   3.39555170)
    (7380.00,   3.39331360)
    (7390.00,   3.39098280)
    (7400.00,   3.38859900)
    (7410.00,   3.38605630)
    (7420.00,   3.38344740)
    (7430.00,   3.38071930)
    (7440.00,   3.37789850)
    (7450.00,   3.37493200)
    (7460.00,   3.37185960)
    (7470.00,   3.36866800)
    (7480.00,   3.36534390)
    (7490.00,   3.36188740)
    (7500.00,   3.35829850)
    (7510.00,   3.35456370)
    (7520.00,   3.35069670)
    (7530.00,   3.34665760)
    (7540.00,   3.34251240)
    (7550.00,   3.33815540)
    (7560.00,   3.33367920)
    (7570.00,   3.32900440)
    (7580.00,   3.32415730)
    (7590.00,   3.31915140)
    (7600.00,   3.31396010)
    (7610.00,   3.30850390)
    (7620.00,   3.30290200)
    (7630.00,   3.29711470)
    (7640.00,   3.29106260)
    (7650.00,   3.28479850)
    (7660.00,   3.27834910)
    (7670.00,   3.27160830)
    (7680.00,   3.26469530)
    (7690.00,   3.25749100)
    (7700.00,   3.24999510)
    (7710.00,   3.24223450)
    (7720.00,   3.23424890)
    (7730.00,   3.22591890)
    (7740.00,   3.21720490)
    (7750.00,   3.20817300)
    (7760.00,   3.19883650)
    (7770.00,   3.18901010)
    (7780.00,   3.17878630)
    (7790.00,   3.16799310)
    (7800.00,   3.15665690)
    (7810.00,   3.14487030)
    (7820.00,   3.13236870)
    (7830.00,   3.11952280)
    (7840.00,   3.10576310)
    (7850.00,   3.09128830)
    (7860.00,   3.07588640)
    (7870.00,   3.05955760)
    (7880.00,   3.04197060)
    (7890.00,   3.02325770)
    (7900.00,   3.00290290)
    (7910.00,   2.98081320)
    (7920.00,   2.95667090)
    (7930.00,   2.93001200)
    (7940.00,   2.90034720)
    (7950.00,   2.86670940)
    (7960.00,   2.82773460)
    (7970.00,   2.78127740)
    (7980.00,   2.72450340)
    (7990.00,   2.64982490)

};
|- (axis cs:0,0) -- cycle;


% Preenchimento da área abaixo da curba

\addplot
[blue!80!black,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5]
coordinates
{   
(  0.00,   4.20309810)
( 10.00,   4.15772650)
( 20.00,   4.15530300)
( 30.00,   4.15246890)
( 40.00,   4.14982030)
( 50.00,   4.14731730)
( 60.00,   4.14493360)
( 70.00,   4.14261600)
( 80.00,   4.14041760)
( 90.00,   4.13827220)
(100.00,   4.13617980)
(110.00,   4.13410060)
(120.00,   4.13208760)
(130.00,   4.13008790)
(140.00,   4.12812790)
(150.00,   4.12616790)
(160.00,   4.12422120)
(170.00,   4.12230090)
(180.00,   4.12039390)
(190.00,   4.11852660)
(200.00,   4.11664610)
(210.00,   4.11479200)
(220.00,   4.11295120)
(230.00,   4.11109720)
(240.00,   4.10926960)
(250.00,   4.10742880)
(260.00,   4.10564090)
(270.00,   4.10385310)
(280.00,   4.10203880)
(290.00,   4.10025100)
(300.00,   4.09847640)
(310.00,   4.09670180)
(320.00,   4.09491390)
(330.00,   4.09316580)
(340.00,   4.09144420)
(350.00,   4.08969610)
(360.00,   4.08796120)
(370.00,   4.08623950)
(380.00,   4.08447820)
(390.00,   4.08276980)
(400.00,   4.08106140)
(410.00,   4.07932660)
(420.00,   4.07759170)
(430.00,   4.07590980)
(440.00,   4.07421470)
(450.00,   4.07253280)
(460.00,   4.07081120)
(470.00,   4.06912930)
(480.00,   4.06746070)
(490.00,   4.06577880)
(500.00,   4.06409690)
(510.00,   4.06244150)
(520.00,   4.06073310)
(530.00,   4.05907770)
(540.00,   4.05743560)
(550.00,   4.05576690)
(560.00,   4.05409830)
(570.00,   4.05244290)
(580.00,   4.05077420)
(590.00,   4.04913210)
(600.00,   4.04748990)
(610.00,   4.04583450)
(620.00,   4.04421880)
(630.00,   4.04256340)
(640.00,   4.04094780)
(650.00,   4.03929240)
(660.00,   4.03766340)
(670.00,   4.03602130)
(680.00,   4.03441890)
(690.00,   4.03278990)
(700.00,   4.03114780)
(710.00,   4.02951890)
(720.00,   4.02791640)
(730.00,   4.02628750)
(740.00,   4.02468510)
(750.00,   4.02306940)
(760.00,   4.02145380)
(770.00,   4.01985130)
(780.00,   4.01823570)
(790.00,   4.01662000)
(800.00,   4.01500430)
(810.00,   4.01341510)
(820.00,   4.01181270)
(830.00,   4.01021030)
(840.00,   4.00860780)
(850.00,   4.00704510)
(860.00,   4.00544270)
(870.00,   4.00382700)
(880.00,   4.00225110)
(890.00,   4.00067520)
(900.00,   3.99908600)
(910.00,   3.99747030)
(920.00,   3.99588110)
(930.00,   3.99427870)
(940.00,   3.99268950)
(950.00,   3.99108710)
(960.00,   3.98951110)
(970.00,   3.98790870)
(980.00,   3.98631950)
(990.00,   3.98471710)
(1000.00,   3.98315420) 
}
|- (axis cs:0,0) -- cycle;


%\addplot
%[blue!80!black,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5]
%coordinates
%{  (4,12.15)
%   (5,12.12)
%   (6,12.08)   
%}
%|- (axis cs:0,0) -- cycle;

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### My Result

[image: Result of the code]

### The result I want

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use fillbetween for that. (**EDIT**: Added labels and replaced ñ by `\~n` for being able to compile with `pdflatex`.)

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % utf8 Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} % <-added


\begin{document}

% Definição do Estilo e dos Eixos   
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest,xmin=0,xmax=8500,ymin=2}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xlabel=Tempo(s), ylabel=Tens\~ao (V),,grid=major,ytick distance=0.5]

\addlegendentry{Curva de Descarga}

% Plotagem dos Pontos para plotagem do gráfico

\addplot[color=red,mark=x,name path=A] coordinates {    

    (  0.00,   4.20309810)
    ( 10.00,   4.15772650)
    ( 20.00,   4.15530300)
    ( 30.00,   4.15246890)
    ( 40.00,   4.14982030)
    ( 50.00,   4.14731730)
    ( 60.00,   4.14493360)
    ( 70.00,   4.14261600)
    ( 80.00,   4.14041760)
    ( 90.00,   4.13827220)
    (100.00,   4.13617980)
    (110.00,   4.13410060)
    (120.00,   4.13208760)
    (130.00,   4.13008790)
    (140.00,   4.12812790)
    (150.00,   4.12616790)
    (160.00,   4.12422120)
    (170.00,   4.12230090)
    (180.00,   4.12039390)
    (190.00,   4.11852660)
    (200.00,   4.11664610)
    (210.00,   4.11479200)
    (220.00,   4.11295120)
    (230.00,   4.11109720)
    (240.00,   4.10926960)
    (250.00,   4.10742880)
    (260.00,   4.10564090)
    (270.00,   4.10385310)
    (280.00,   4.10203880)
    (290.00,   4.10025100)
    (300.00,   4.09847640)
    (310.00,   4.09670180)
    (320.00,   4.09491390)
    (330.00,   4.09316580)
    (340.00,   4.09144420)
    (350.00,   4.08969610)
    (360.00,   4.08796120)
    (370.00,   4.08623950)
    (380.00,   4.08447820)
    (390.00,   4.08276980)
    (400.00,   4.08106140)
    (410.00,   4.07932660)
    (420.00,   4.07759170)
    (430.00,   4.07590980)
    (440.00,   4.07421470)
    (450.00,   4.07253280)
    (460.00,   4.07081120)
    (470.00,   4.06912930)
    (480.00,   4.06746070)
    (490.00,   4.06577880)
    (500.00,   4.06409690)
    (510.00,   4.06244150)
    (520.00,   4.06073310)
    (530.00,   4.05907770)
    (540.00,   4.05743560)
    (550.00,   4.05576690)
    (560.00,   4.05409830)
    (570.00,   4.05244290)
    (580.00,   4.05077420)
    (590.00,   4.04913210)
    (600.00,   4.04748990)
    (610.00,   4.04583450)
    (620.00,   4.04421880)
    (630.00,   4.04256340)
    (640.00,   4.04094780)
    (650.00,   4.03929240)
    (660.00,   4.03766340)
    (670.00,   4.03602130)
    (680.00,   4.03441890)
    (690.00,   4.03278990)
    (700.00,   4.03114780)
    (710.00,   4.02951890)
    (720.00,   4.02791640)
    (730.00,   4.02628750)
    (740.00,   4.02468510)
    (750.00,   4.02306940)
    (760.00,   4.02145380)
    (770.00,   4.01985130)
    (780.00,   4.01823570)
    (790.00,   4.01662000)
    (800.00,   4.01500430)
    (810.00,   4.01341510)
    (820.00,   4.01181270)
    (830.00,   4.01021030)
    (840.00,   4.00860780)
    (850.00,   4.00704510)
    (860.00,   4.00544270)
    (870.00,   4.00382700)
    (880.00,   4.00225110)
    (890.00,   4.00067520)
    (900.00,   3.99908600)
    (910.00,   3.99747030)
    (920.00,   3.99588110)
    (930.00,   3.99427870)
    (940.00,   3.99268950)
    (950.00,   3.99108710)
    (960.00,   3.98951110)
    (970.00,   3.98790870)
    (980.00,   3.98631950)
    (990.00,   3.98471710)
    (1000.00,   3.98315420)
    (1010.00,   3.98153850)
    (1020.00,   3.97994930)
    (1030.00,   3.97837340)
    (1040.00,   3.97679740)
    (1050.00,   3.97523470)
    (1060.00,   3.97206960)
    (1070.00,   3.97049370)
    (1080.00,   3.96894420)
    (1090.00,   3.96735500)
    (1100.00,   3.96581880)
    (1110.00,   3.96428260)
    (1120.00,   3.96271990)
    (1130.00,   3.96118370)
    (1140.00,   3.95962100)
    (1150.00,   3.95808480)
    (1160.00,   3.95653530)
    (1170.00,   3.95498590)
    (1180.00,   3.95343640)
    (1190.00,   3.95191340)
    (1200.00,   3.95039050)
    (1210.00,   3.94884100)
    (1220.00,   3.94730480)
    (1230.00,   3.94578180)
    (1240.00,   3.94425890)
    (1250.00,   3.94269620)
    (1260.00,   3.94122620)
    (1270.00,   3.93967670)
    (1280.00,   3.93818020)
    (1290.00,   3.93665730)
    (1300.00,   3.93514750)
    (1310.00,   3.93365110)
    (1320.00,   3.93212810)
    (1330.00,   3.93790210)
    (1340.00,   3.93643210)
    (1350.00,   3.93493570)
    (1360.00,   3.93338620)
    (1370.00,   3.93190300)
    (1380.00,   3.93039320)
    (1390.00,   3.92888350)
    (1400.00,   3.92737380)
    (1410.00,   3.92586410)
    (1420.00,   3.92436760)
    (1430.00,   3.92284460)
    (1440.00,   3.92136140)
    (1450.00,   3.91987810)
    (1460.00,   3.91836840)
    (1470.00,   3.91688520)
    (1480.00,   3.91537540)
    (1490.00,   3.91389220)
    (1500.00,   3.91240890)
    (1510.00,   3.91095220)
    (1520.00,   3.90944250)
    (1530.00,   3.90795920)
    (1540.00,   3.90648920)
    (1550.00,   3.90503250)
    (1560.00,   3.90356250)
    (1570.00,   3.90209250)
    (1580.00,   3.90064900)
    (1590.00,   3.89919220)
    (1600.00,   3.89777520)
    (1610.00,   3.89633170)
    (1620.00,   3.89488820)
    (1630.00,   3.89343140)
    (1640.00,   3.89200120)
    (1650.00,   3.89055760)
    (1660.00,   3.88912740)
    (1670.00,   3.88772360)
    (1680.00,   3.88630660)
    (1690.00,   3.88487630)
    (1700.00,   3.88344600)
    (1710.00,   3.88204230)
    (1720.00,   3.88061200)
    (1730.00,   3.87924750)
    (1740.00,   3.87780400)
    (1750.00,   3.87644000)
    (1760.00,   3.87500970)
    (1770.00,   3.87361920)
    (1780.00,   3.87221540)
    (1790.00,   3.87081160)
    (1800.00,   3.86942110)
    (1810.00,   3.86801730)
    (1820.00,   3.86664000)
    (1830.00,   3.86524950)
    (1840.00,   3.86385890)
    (1850.00,   3.86249490)
    (1860.00,   3.86109110)
    (1870.00,   3.85971380)
    (1880.00,   3.85834980)
    (1890.00,   3.85697250)
    (1900.00,   3.85560840)
    (1910.00,   3.85424440)
    (1920.00,   3.85289360)
    (1930.00,   3.85155600)
    (1940.00,   3.85019190)
    (1950.00,   3.84884110)
    (1960.00,   3.84750360)
    (1970.00,   3.84615280)
    (1980.00,   3.84480200)
    (1990.00,   3.84346440)
    (2000.00,   3.84212680)
    (2010.00,   3.84078930)
    (2020.00,   3.83946490)
    (2030.00,   3.83816710)
    (2040.00,   3.83684280)
    (2050.00,   3.83553170)
    (2060.00,   3.83420740)
    (2070.00,   3.83290950)
    (2080.00,   3.83158520)
    (2090.00,   3.83027420)
    (2100.00,   3.82896310)
    (2110.00,   3.82766520)
    (2120.00,   3.82636740)
    (2130.00,   3.82508280)
    (2140.00,   3.82375850)
    (2150.00,   3.82247390)
    (2160.00,   3.82118930)
    (2170.00,   3.81991800)
    (2180.00,   3.81865990)
    (2190.00,   3.81737530)
    (2200.00,   3.81607740)
    (2210.00,   3.81484580)
    (2220.00,   3.81358770)
    (2230.00,   3.81230310)
    (2240.00,   3.81105830)
    (2250.00,   3.80978690)
    (2260.00,   3.80854200)
    (2270.00,   3.80729720)
    (2280.00,   3.80607880)
    (2290.00,   3.80479420)
    (2300.00,   3.80356260)
    (2310.00,   3.80233100)
    (2320.00,   3.80108610)
    (2330.00,   3.79984130)
    (2340.00,   3.79860960)
    (2350.00,   3.79736480)
    (2360.00,   3.79615960)
    (2370.00,   3.79494130)
    (2380.00,   3.79372290)
    (2390.00,   3.79251780)
    (2400.00,   3.79131260)
    (2410.00,   3.79010750)
    (2420.00,   3.78891560)
    (2430.00,   3.78769720)
    (2440.00,   3.78651860)
    (2450.00,   3.78531340)
    (2460.00,   3.78413480)
    (2470.00,   3.78295620)
    (2480.00,   3.78177750)
    (2490.00,   3.78059890)
    (2500.00,   3.77942020)
    (2510.00,   3.77824160)
    (2520.00,   3.77706290)
    (2530.00,   3.77593730)
    (2540.00,   3.77475850)
    (2550.00,   3.77359310)
    (2560.00,   3.77240120)
    (2570.00,   3.77124910)
    (2580.00,   3.77011010)
    (2590.00,   3.76897120)
    (2600.00,   3.76780580)
    (2610.00,   3.76668010)
    (2620.00,   3.76554120)
    (2630.00,   3.76440230)
    (2640.00,   3.76327660)
    (2650.00,   3.76216420)
    (2660.00,   3.76101210)
    (2670.00,   3.75988640)
    (2680.00,   3.75878720)
    (2690.00,   3.75766150)
    (2700.00,   3.75654910)
    (2710.00,   3.75543670)
    (2720.00,   3.75436400)
    (2730.00,   3.75325150)
    (2740.00,   3.75217880)
    (2750.00,   3.75107960)
    (2760.00,   3.74999370)
    (2770.00,   3.74890780)
    (2780.00,   3.74786150)
    (2790.00,   3.74677560)
    (2800.00,   3.74567640)
    (2810.00,   3.74461700)
    (2820.00,   3.74350450)
    (2830.00,   3.74245830)
    (2840.00,   3.74141210)
    (2850.00,   3.74035260)
    (2860.00,   3.73927990)
    (2870.00,   3.73822050)
    (2880.00,   3.73718750)
    (2890.00,   3.73611480)
    (2900.00,   3.73509510)
    (2910.00,   3.73404890)
    (2920.00,   3.73301590)
    (2930.00,   3.73199620)
    (2940.00,   3.73096320)
    (2950.00,   3.72995670)
    (2960.00,   3.72895020)
    (2970.00,   3.72791730)
    (2980.00,   3.72695050)
    (2990.00,   3.72591750)
    (3000.00,   3.72493750)
    (3010.00,   3.72393110)
    (3020.00,   3.72295110)
    (3030.00,   3.72195780)
    (3040.00,   3.72095130)
    (3050.00,   3.71999780)
    (3060.00,   3.71903110)
    (3070.00,   3.71802460)
    (3080.00,   3.71704460)
    (3090.00,   3.71606460)
    (3100.00,   3.71509780)
    (3110.00,   3.71410460)
    (3120.00,   3.71315110)
    (3130.00,   3.71219760)
    (3140.00,   3.71127060)
    (3150.00,   3.71027730)
    (3160.00,   3.70935030)
    (3170.00,   3.70841000)
    (3180.00,   3.70748300)
    (3190.00,   3.70654270)
    (3200.00,   3.70560250)
    (3210.00,   3.70468870)
    (3220.00,   3.70376170)
    (3230.00,   3.70284790)
    (3240.00,   3.70196060)
    (3250.00,   3.70103350)
    (3260.00,   3.70010650)
    (3270.00,   3.69920600)
    (3280.00,   3.69833190)
    (3290.00,   3.69745790)
    (3300.00,   3.69654410)
    (3310.00,   3.69564360)
    (3320.00,   3.69475630)
    (3330.00,   3.69388220)
    (3340.00,   3.69300820)
    (3350.00,   3.69209440)
    (3360.00,   3.69123360)
    (3370.00,   3.69034630)
    (3380.00,   3.68947220)
    (3390.00,   3.68862470)
    (3400.00,   3.68775060)
    (3410.00,   3.68688980)
    (3420.00,   3.68604220)
    (3430.00,   3.68518140)
    (3440.00,   3.68433390)
    (3450.00,   3.68348630)
    (3460.00,   3.68265200)
    (3470.00,   3.68180440)
    (3480.00,   3.68098330)
    (3490.00,   3.68016220)
    (3500.00,   3.67934120)
    (3510.00,   3.67852010)
    (3520.00,   3.67769900)
    (3530.00,   3.67690440)
    (3540.00,   3.67609660)
    (3550.00,   3.67527550)
    (3560.00,   3.67446770)
    (3570.00,   3.67369960)
    (3580.00,   3.67287850)
    (3590.00,   3.67208390)
    (3600.00,   3.67128930)
    (3610.00,   3.67049470)
    (3620.00,   3.66969990)
    (3630.00,   3.66891860)
    (3640.00,   3.66813720)
    (3650.00,   3.66732940)
    (3660.00,   3.66657450)
    (3670.00,   3.66579320)
    (3680.00,   3.66503830)
    (3690.00,   3.66427020)
    (3700.00,   3.66352860)
    (3710.00,   3.66276050)
    (3720.00,   3.66199240)
    (3730.00,   3.66126400)
    (3740.00,   3.66048260)
    (3750.00,   3.65976750)
    (3760.00,   3.65901260)
    (3770.00,   3.65829750)
    (3780.00,   3.65752940)
    (3790.00,   3.65681430)
    (3800.00,   3.65611240)
    (3810.00,   3.65535750)
    (3820.00,   3.65464240)
    (3830.00,   3.65394050)
    (3840.00,   3.65323860)
    (3850.00,   3.65251020)
    (3860.00,   3.65178180)
    (3870.00,   3.65106670)
    (3880.00,   3.65035160)
    (3890.00,   3.64963640)
    (3900.00,   3.64894780)
    (3910.00,   3.64824590)
    (3920.00,   3.64753080)
    (3930.00,   3.64682890)
    (3940.00,   3.64614020)
    (3950.00,   3.64545160)
    (3960.00,   3.64476290)
    (3970.00,   3.64408750)
    (3980.00,   3.64341210)
    (3990.00,   3.64273670)
    (4000.00,   3.64203480)
    (4010.00,   3.64137270)
    (4020.00,   3.64071050)
    (4030.00,   3.64003510)
    (4040.00,   3.63935970)
    (4050.00,   3.63871080)
    (4060.00,   3.63804860)
    (4070.00,   3.63738650)
    (4080.00,   3.63672430)
    (4090.00,   3.63606220)
    (4100.00,   3.63541320)
    (4110.00,   3.63476430)
    (4120.00,   3.63411540)
    (4130.00,   3.63346650)
    (4140.00,   3.63283080)
    (4150.00,   3.63218190)
    (4160.00,   3.63153300)
    (4170.00,   3.63089730)
    (4180.00,   3.63024840)
    (4190.00,   3.62961270)
    (4200.00,   3.62896380)
    (4210.00,   3.62830160)
    (4220.00,   3.62770570)
    (4230.00,   3.62708330)
    (4240.00,   3.62644760)
    (4250.00,   3.62582520)
    (4260.00,   3.62520270)
    (4270.00,   3.62458030)
    (4280.00,   3.62395790)
    (4290.00,   3.62336190)
    (4300.00,   3.62275270)
    (4310.00,   3.62211710)
    (4320.00,   3.62153440)
    (4330.00,   3.62092520)
    (4340.00,   3.62032920)
    (4350.00,   3.61972000)
    (4360.00,   3.61911080)
    (4370.00,   3.61850170)
    (4380.00,   3.61791900)
    (4390.00,   3.61730980)
    (4400.00,   3.61671380)
    (4410.00,   3.61611790)
    (4420.00,   3.61552190)
    (4430.00,   3.61491270)
    (4440.00,   3.61431680)
    (4450.00,   3.61372090)
    (4460.00,   3.61313820)
    (4470.00,   3.61254220)
    (4480.00,   3.61194630)
    (4490.00,   3.61135030)
    (4500.00,   3.61078090)
    (4510.00,   3.61019820)
    (4520.00,   3.60957570)
    (4530.00,   3.60900630)
    (4540.00,   3.60845010)
    (4550.00,   3.60786740)
    (4560.00,   3.60728470)
    (4570.00,   3.60671520)
    (4580.00,   3.60615900)
    (4590.00,   3.60558950)
    (4600.00,   3.60500680)
    (4610.00,   3.60445060)
    (4620.00,   3.60389440)
    (4630.00,   3.60333820)
    (4640.00,   3.60272900)
    (4650.00,   3.60217280)
    (4660.00,   3.60162980)
    (4670.00,   3.60106030)
    (4680.00,   3.60046440)
    (4690.00,   3.59992140)
    (4700.00,   3.59935200)
    (4710.00,   3.59879580)
    (4720.00,   3.59822630)
    (4730.00,   3.59765680)
    (4740.00,   3.59710060)
    (4750.00,   3.59654440)
    (4760.00,   3.59598820)
    (4770.00,   3.59541870)
    (4780.00,   3.59484930)
    (4790.00,   3.59431960)
    (4800.00,   3.59376330)
    (4810.00,   3.59320710)
    (4820.00,   3.59263770)
    (4830.00,   3.59209470)
    (4840.00,   3.59153850)
    (4850.00,   3.59100870)
    (4860.00,   3.59043930)
    (4870.00,   3.58988310)
    (4880.00,   3.58934010)
    (4890.00,   3.58879710)
    (4900.00,   3.58824090)
    (4910.00,   3.58769790)
    (4920.00,   3.58712850)
    (4930.00,   3.58658550)
    (4940.00,   3.58604250)
    (4950.00,   3.58548630)
    (4960.00,   3.58493010)
    (4970.00,   3.58436070)
    (4980.00,   3.58381770)
    (4990.00,   3.58327470)
    (5000.00,   3.58273170)
    (5010.00,   3.58217550)
    (5020.00,   3.58163260)
    (5030.00,   3.58108960)
    (5040.00,   3.58054660)
    (5050.00,   3.57999040)
    (5060.00,   3.57944740)
    (5070.00,   3.57944740)
    (5080.00,   3.57944740)
    (5090.00,   3.57944740)
    (5100.00,   3.57944740)
    (5110.00,   3.57944740)
    (5120.00,   3.57944740)
    (5130.00,   3.57944740)
    (5140.00,   3.57944740)
    (5150.00,   3.57944740)
    (5160.00,   3.57944740)
    (5170.00,   3.57944740)
    (5180.00,   3.57944740)
    (5190.00,   3.57944740)
    (5200.00,   3.57944740)
    (5210.00,   3.57188560)
    (5220.00,   3.57138230)
    (5230.00,   3.57079960)
    (5240.00,   3.57024340)
    (5250.00,   3.56970040)
    (5260.00,   3.56914420)
    (5270.00,   3.56860120)
    (5280.00,   3.56807150)
    (5290.00,   3.56750200)
    (5300.00,   3.56698560)
    (5310.00,   3.56640290)
    (5320.00,   3.56585990)
    (5330.00,   3.56531690)
    (5340.00,   3.56474710)
    (5350.00,   3.56419080)
    (5360.00,   3.56366110)
    (5370.00,   3.56310490)
    (5380.00,   3.56253540)
    (5390.00,   3.56197920)
    (5400.00,   3.56146270)
    (5410.00,   3.56089330)
    (5420.00,   3.56035030)
    (5430.00,   3.55979410)
    (5440.00,   3.55921140)
    (5450.00,   3.55865520)
    (5460.00,   3.55808570)
    (5470.00,   3.55754280)
    (5480.00,   3.55698650)
    (5490.00,   3.55639060)
    (5500.00,   3.55583440)
    (5510.00,   3.55527820)
    (5520.00,   3.55470870)
    (5530.00,   3.55411280)
    (5540.00,   3.55354330)
    (5550.00,   3.55297380)
    (5560.00,   3.55240440)
    (5570.00,   3.55182170)
    (5580.00,   3.55125220)
    (5590.00,   3.55068280)
    (5600.00,   3.55010010)
    (5610.00,   3.54951740)
    (5620.00,   3.54892140)
    (5630.00,   3.54837840)
    (5640.00,   3.54775600)
    (5650.00,   3.54719980)
    (5660.00,   3.54659060)
    (5670.00,   3.54599470)
    (5680.00,   3.54539870)
    (5690.00,   3.54482930)
    (5700.00,   3.54422010)
    (5710.00,   3.54363740)
    (5720.00,   3.54304140)
    (5730.00,   3.54244550)
    (5740.00,   3.54180980)
    (5750.00,   3.54121390)
    (5760.00,   3.54060470)
    (5770.00,   3.53998230)
    (5780.00,   3.53937310)
    (5790.00,   3.53876390)
    (5800.00,   3.53814140)
    (5810.00,   3.53751900)
    (5820.00,   3.53688330)
    (5830.00,   3.53624770)
    (5840.00,   3.53565170)
    (5850.00,   3.53498960)
    (5860.00,   3.53438040)
    (5870.00,   3.53374470)
    (5880.00,   3.53312230)
    (5890.00,   3.53248660)
    (5900.00,   3.53183770)
    (5910.00,   3.53118880)
    (5920.00,   3.53056630)
    (5930.00,   3.52990420)
    (5940.00,   3.52928170)
    (5950.00,   3.52861960)
    (5960.00,   3.52798390)
    (5970.00,   3.52732170)
    (5980.00,   3.52667280)
    (5990.00,   3.52602390)
    (6000.00,   3.52537500)
    (6010.00,   3.52469960)
    (6020.00,   3.52402420)
    (6030.00,   3.52337530)
    (6040.00,   3.52268660)
    (6050.00,   3.52199800)
    (6060.00,   3.52130930)
    (6070.00,   3.52063390)
    (6080.00,   3.51997180)
    (6090.00,   3.51929640)
    (6100.00,   3.51858120)
    (6110.00,   3.51791910)
    (6120.00,   3.51723040)
    (6130.00,   3.51652850)
    (6140.00,   3.51585310)
    (6150.00,   3.51515120)
    (6160.00,   3.51446260)
    (6170.00,   3.51377390)
    (6180.00,   3.51311180)
    (6190.00,   3.51237020)
    (6200.00,   3.51168150)
    (6210.00,   3.51099290)
    (6220.00,   3.51027770)
    (6230.00,   3.50956260)
    (6240.00,   3.50888720)
    (6250.00,   3.50814560)
    (6260.00,   3.50745690)
    (6270.00,   3.50672850)
    (6280.00,   3.50601340)
    (6290.00,   3.50525860)
    (6300.00,   3.50454340)
    (6310.00,   3.50381500)
    (6320.00,   3.50308670)
    (6330.00,   3.50234500)
    (6340.00,   3.50160340)
    (6350.00,   3.50082210)
    (6360.00,   3.50008050)
    (6370.00,   3.49932560)
    (6380.00,   3.49854420)
    (6390.00,   3.49781590)
    (6400.00,   3.49703450)
    (6410.00,   3.49626640)
    (6420.00,   3.49548510)
    (6430.00,   3.49470370)
    (6440.00,   3.49392240)
    (6450.00,   3.49314100)
    (6460.00,   3.49234640)
    (6470.00,   3.49155180)
    (6480.00,   3.49077050)
    (6490.00,   3.48996260)
    (6500.00,   3.48914160)
    (6510.00,   3.48832050)
    (6520.00,   3.48751260)
    (6530.00,   3.48669160)
    (6540.00,   3.48583080)
    (6550.00,   3.48502290)
    (6560.00,   3.48414890)
    (6570.00,   3.48330130)
    (6580.00,   3.48244050)
    (6590.00,   3.48157970)
    (6600.00,   3.48070560)
    (6610.00,   3.47983160)
    (6620.00,   3.47894430)
    (6630.00,   3.47807020)
    (6640.00,   3.47716970)
    (6650.00,   3.47628240)
    (6660.00,   3.47540840)
    (6670.00,   3.47452110)
    (6680.00,   3.47363380)
    (6690.00,   3.47273320)
    (6700.00,   3.47183270)
    (6710.00,   3.47094540)
    (6720.00,   3.47007130)
    (6730.00,   3.46918400)
    (6740.00,   3.46827030)
    (6750.00,   3.46742270)
    (6760.00,   3.46652220)
    (6770.00,   3.46562160)
    (6780.00,   3.46476080)
    (6790.00,   3.46390000)
    (6800.00,   3.46299950)
    (6810.00,   3.46215190)
    (6820.00,   3.46126460)
    (6830.00,   3.46039060)
    (6840.00,   3.45948990)
    (6850.00,   3.45862910)
    (6860.00,   3.45775510)
    (6870.00,   3.45688100)
    (6880.00,   3.45598050)
    (6890.00,   3.45511970)
    (6900.00,   3.45424560)
    (6910.00,   3.45333180)
    (6920.00,   3.45245780)
    (6930.00,   3.45155720)
    (6940.00,   3.45065670)
    (6950.00,   3.44976940)
    (6960.00,   3.44885560)
    (6970.00,   3.44794180)
    (6980.00,   3.44702810)
    (6990.00,   3.44610100)
    (7000.00,   3.44516080)
    (7010.00,   3.44423370)
    (7020.00,   3.44325370)
    (7030.00,   3.44234000)
    (7040.00,   3.44134670)
    (7050.00,   3.44035350)
    (7060.00,   3.43940000)
    (7070.00,   3.43836700)
    (7080.00,   3.43733400)
    (7090.00,   3.43630110)
    (7100.00,   3.43525480)
    (7110.00,   3.43416890)
    (7120.00,   3.43306970)
    (7130.00,   3.43197050)
    (7140.00,   3.43087130)
    (7150.00,   3.42969270)
    (7160.00,   3.42851400)
    (7170.00,   3.42733540)
    (7180.00,   3.42611700)
    (7190.00,   3.42487220)
    (7200.00,   3.42361410)
    (7210.00,   3.42232950)
    (7220.00,   3.42099190)
    (7230.00,   3.41962780)
    (7240.00,   3.41823730)
    (7250.00,   3.41679380)
    (7260.00,   3.41531060)
    (7270.00,   3.41380080)
    (7280.00,   3.41223810)
    (7290.00,   3.41062250)
    (7300.00,   3.40898030)
    (7310.00,   3.40725870)
    (7320.00,   3.40549730)
    (7330.00,   3.40365650)
    (7340.00,   3.40172300)
    (7350.00,   3.39974980)
    (7360.00,   3.39771030)
    (7370.00,   3.39555170)
    (7380.00,   3.39331360)
    (7390.00,   3.39098280)
    (7400.00,   3.38859900)
    (7410.00,   3.38605630)
    (7420.00,   3.38344740)
    (7430.00,   3.38071930)
    (7440.00,   3.37789850)
    (7450.00,   3.37493200)
    (7460.00,   3.37185960)
    (7470.00,   3.36866800)
    (7480.00,   3.36534390)
    (7490.00,   3.36188740)
    (7500.00,   3.35829850)
    (7510.00,   3.35456370)
    (7520.00,   3.35069670)
    (7530.00,   3.34665760)
    (7540.00,   3.34251240)
    (7550.00,   3.33815540)
    (7560.00,   3.33367920)
    (7570.00,   3.32900440)
    (7580.00,   3.32415730)
    (7590.00,   3.31915140)
    (7600.00,   3.31396010)
    (7610.00,   3.30850390)
    (7620.00,   3.30290200)
    (7630.00,   3.29711470)
    (7640.00,   3.29106260)
    (7650.00,   3.28479850)
    (7660.00,   3.27834910)
    (7670.00,   3.27160830)
    (7680.00,   3.26469530)
    (7690.00,   3.25749100)
    (7700.00,   3.24999510)
    (7710.00,   3.24223450)
    (7720.00,   3.23424890)
    (7730.00,   3.22591890)
    (7740.00,   3.21720490)
    (7750.00,   3.20817300)
    (7760.00,   3.19883650)
    (7770.00,   3.18901010)
    (7780.00,   3.17878630)
    (7790.00,   3.16799310)
    (7800.00,   3.15665690)
    (7810.00,   3.14487030)
    (7820.00,   3.13236870)
    (7830.00,   3.11952280)
    (7840.00,   3.10576310)
    (7850.00,   3.09128830)
    (7860.00,   3.07588640)
    (7870.00,   3.05955760)
    (7880.00,   3.04197060)
    (7890.00,   3.02325770)
    (7900.00,   3.00290290)
    (7910.00,   2.98081320)
    (7920.00,   2.95667090)
    (7930.00,   2.93001200)
    (7940.00,   2.90034720)
    (7950.00,   2.86670940)
    (7960.00,   2.82773460)
    (7970.00,   2.78127740)
    (7980.00,   2.72450340)
    (7990.00,   2.64982490)

};
|- (axis cs:0,0) -- cycle;

    \path [name path=B]
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},2) --
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},2);

    \addplot [green!50] fill between [
        of=A and B,
        soft clip={domain=0:1200},
    ];

    \addplot [purple!50] fill between [
        of=A and B,
        soft clip={domain=1200:6000},
    ];

    \addplot [blue!50] fill between [
        of=A and B,
        soft clip={domain=6000:8000},
    ];
    \path (600,3) node[rotate=90,font=\sffamily\large] {NAME 1}
    (3600,2.75) node[font=\sffamily\large] {NAME 2}
    (7000,2.75) node[rotate=90,font=\sffamily\large] {NAME 3};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm learning a lot with you answers. Really helped me every time I ask something. Can you show me how to change the font of the Name 1, Name 2 and Name 3 to a more beautiful font ?

Comment: @SrnLord The font is controlled by the directive `,font=\sffamily\large`.